# Website footer does not get overlayed with modal Popup Form

Tags: html, css

I have a modal popup Form for my website whose background should overlay the whole viewport. The website contains a header and a footer and the modal is triggered by a simple javascript. Everything works fine except that my footer is still displayed on top and not overlayed with the modal background.

Here's my css code:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #688596;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #676767;
}

.modalBackground {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.6);
}
```

The javascript sets display:none to display:block for .modalBackground.
As I said, everything works fine but the footer still sits on top. What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to raise the z-index. Try "3" for the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the value of `z-index` of `.modalBackground` to higher than that of your header and footer. Currently the `z-index` of `.footer` is `2`. So the `.modalBackground` 's `z-index` should be more than `2`. Try setting it to `999`. So the class `.modalBackground` should be like this in your css:

```
.modalBackground {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Somehow I had in mind that the z-Index represents the priority and low Indexes are above high Indexes -.- Works perfectly now! Thank you guys!

Comment: Yeah, I can understand. The calculations are based on x, y and z axis. So bringing a div forward or backward in css is z axis. Higher z axis is, well, higher in the stack. That is how I picture it. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `z-index` of  `footer` is greater then the `z-index` of your `modal`.

> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Read more about `z-index` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Try this (I just changed the `z-index`es):

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #688596;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #676767;
}

.modalBackground {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.6);
}
```